# Display the data from kendo-grid to html using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am working on [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/660lgvoKU84s09Bv7nW1?p=preview) . It displays the data using kendo - grid. However, what I need is when I click on a particular row in the table, all its content get fetched in an object and using that object I can display its fields below the table. How can I achieve that? Also, I believe we need to modify this code as well if we are using objects to display the fields. Any help would be appreciated.

```
First Name: {{FirstName}}<br>
Last Name: {{LastName}}<br>
Country: {{Country}}<br>
City: {{City}}<br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to listen for row selection (change event), and get the selected row, then bind it to angular variable inside your scope as describe in this [update](http://plnkr.co/edit/q0DI2x9IwPz0D7hbutSe?p=preview)

The key here is the change event triggered upon selection/deselection

```
grid configs
...
change: function(e) {
    var selection = this.select(),
        selectedItem
    ;

    if(selection && this.dataItem(selection)) {
        $scope.selectedItem = this.dataItem(selection).toJSON();
    } else {
        $scope.selectedItem = {};
    }

    $scope.$apply();
}
...
grid configs
```

Answer (score 0):

Two changes required in your code:

1) in HTML add on-change event handler function `<kendo-grid options="mainGridOptions" k-on-change="handleChangeEvent(data, dataItem, columns)">  </kendo-grid>`

2) in JavaScript

- Set Kendo grid as selectable `sortable: true`
- Define  `$scope.handleChangeEvent` function

**Code:**
**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" />

  <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="example" ng-app="KendoDemos">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <kendo-grid options="mainGridOptions" k-on-change="handleChangeEvent(data, dataItem, columns)">  </kendo-grid>

      <h5>You selected: </h5>
First Name: {{FirstName}}<br>
Last Name: {{LastName}}<br>
Country: {{Country}}<br>
City: {{City}}<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And **JavaScript:**

```
 angular.module("KendoDemos", ["kendo.directives"])
       .controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {

           $scope.handleChangeEvent = function(data, dataItem, columns) {

         $scope.FirstName=dataItem.FirstName;
         $scope.LastName=dataItem.LastName;
         $scope.Country=dataItem.Country;
         $scope.City = dataItem.City;

      };

           $scope.mainGridOptions = {
               dataSource: {
                   type: "odata",
                   transport: {
                       read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Employees"
                   },
                   pageSize: 5,
                   serverPaging: true,
                   serverSorting: true
               },
               selectable: "row",
               sortable: true,
               pageable: true,
               dataBound: function () {
                   this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
               },
               columns: [{
                   field: "FirstName",
                   title: "First Name",
                   width: "120px"
               }, {
                   field: "LastName",
                   title: "Last Name",
                   width: "120px"
               }, {
                   field: "Country",
                   width: "120px"
               }, {
                   field: "City",
                   width: "120px"
               }, {
                   field: "Title"
               }]
           };
       });
```